# Create cookie for the domain using javascript while the page is accessed using IP address

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have  a page that sets a cookie using javascript and it works fine. But when I access the page using IP address the cookie is created for the IP address and not for the domain. Is there a way I could create the cookie using javascript for the domain name when the site is accessed using IP address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I doubt that there is a way to do this since this feature of browsers is there for our security. Is there any way you could simply detect that the user is not on a fully qualified domain name and redirect to the domain?

Comment: Why do you need to access the site with the IP address as well as with the domain name?